# C precompile is case-insenstive?

Tags: c++, c

I am writing the following

```
#ifdef points 
#define points

class Points
{
};

#endif
```

later, I found I cannot declare Points point;

I have to change to

```
#ifdef points_h
#define points_h
```

So, ifdef is case-insensitive?

Comment: Post [a Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the error is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Are you sure that's what you wrote? Your `class Point` is missing a semicolon, so it's a syntax error. Also, what's the point of `#define points` if `points` is already defined? That will give you a redefinition error. Finally, are you sure that the error is on `Points point;` and not `Points points;`?

Comment: Raymond, you are right; it is not Point be defined, but points be defined. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not try it yourself?

```
#include <iostream>

#define points

int main() {
    #ifdef Points
      std::cout << "yes";
    #else
      std::cout << "no"; //this happens
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```